# "VT in BIOS" should i enable them?

Tags: bios, vt-x

Recently, I've downloaded an App name  **"LDPlayer"** which is used for games in my PC **" HP EliteBook 840-Windows10 "**...
when I download this, after installing it want me to enable my **"VT in BIOS"** .. I'm kinda worried that I may harm my PC or it may have some security issues...

**So Should I enable this or not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDPlayer is an "android emulator". More correctly it should be called an Android Virtual Machine as there is no platform emulation involved here.

What it is asking you to do by enabling VT is to tell your computer that you may be using virtual machines and allow the processor and programs to use extensions in the hardware to accelerate the running of virtual machines like this one.

Virtual machine hardware is of itself not a security risk, but it has the potential to be used by malware.

If you want to use the emulator then enable it, if you do not regularly download malware then the risk is minimal and most machines these days have VT enabled by default without issue.

Comment: oh Thanks ... its means i should enable it 

Answer (score 2):

VT-x is Intel's name for the "hardware-based virtualization" feature in your CPU. It is safe to enable, and it is normal for LDPlayer to require it, because it does its job by running Android as a virtual machine – just like VirtualBox or VMware, only more specialized.

Comment: Thanxx a lot i'll enable it right now! :)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to enable (VT) Virtualization technology in hp desktop it's pretty easy to enable it start the computer immediately press F10 until BIOS show's up in your screen go to security and find system settings in their will the VT option for your PC/Laptop for more info visit their official website : [www.hp.com](http://www.hp.com)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).